# CSS3 transition within dropzone

Tags: javascript, css, dropzone.js

I have two elements inside in the `dz-message` element in my Dropzone form. One is hidden out of sight (using `overflow:hidden`) and one is visible.

When the form gets the `dz-drag-hover` class, the second element becomes visible when the `dz-message` element is moved up using CSS transitions.

This is the structure of the insi dropzone element:

```
<form class="new-album-dropzone" id="albumDropzone">
    <div class="dz-message">
        <div class="dz-message-empty">
            <div>
                <p>The best way to create collaborative image collections.<br/>No account required.</p>
                <p class="instruction">Drop in some images to get started.</p>
                <p>Or <a href="/sign-in" class="signInModalLink">click here to sign in</a>.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="dz-message-hovered">
            <div>
                <p><span class="instruction">Drop it</span> like it's hot</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

See the `<div>` inside the `dz-message-hovered` and `dz-message-empty` elements? When the cursor ends up inside their body, it causes dropzone to think that `dragend` has happened. That means the `dz-drag-hover` class is removed from the form, and the `dz-message` element starts to transition back down.

I made a video to help demonstrate what I mean: http://quick.as/7OYPiG4Q1 - see how it flickers when the inner elements are dragged over?

Is there anything easy I can do, without forking dropzone, to prevent dropzone from thinking that I'm finished dragging?

Answer (score 4):

I came up with a solution!

I overrided the `dragend` and `dragleave` functions using the regular Dropzone options (no hacking required!) to check if the mouse event occurred outside of the bounds of the dropzone form element. It looks a bit like this:

```
    this.dropzone = new Dropzone(this.$('#albumDropzone')[0], {
        ... other options ...
        dragend: function(e) {
            if (mouseEventOutside(e, $(this.element))) {
                return this.element.classList.remove('dz-drag-hover');
            }
        },
        dragleave: function(e) {
            if (mouseEventOutside(e, $(this.element))) {
                return this.element.classList.remove('dz-drag-hover');
            }
        }
    });
```

And to deal with my flickering that occurs when I hover over the lower element, well, that just changes whenever `dragenter` happens, and I was causing it with the `dragenter` event callback. I just check there if the element being entered was the `dz-message` element, and if it was it doesn't do whatever was causing the flickering. Done with regex: `if (/dz-message/g.test(e.toElement.className)) { }`.

Thanks anybody who took the time to read :) I hope this helps.